# angularjs directive to allow tab character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an angularjs directive that will allow input of tab character on a text field. Its working partially but error is not showing correctly. I want this field to be required too. Here is my code

```
.directive('allowTab', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
                ele.bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
                    var val = this.value;
                    if (e.keyCode === 9 && e.type === 'keydown') { // tab was pressed

                        // get caret position/selection
                        var start = this.selectionStart,
                            end = this.selectionEnd;

                        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
                        this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);

                        // put caret at right position again
                        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

                        c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);
                        // prevent the focus lose
                        return false;

                    }
                    else if(e.keyCode !== 9 && e.type === 'keyup') {
                        if(val === '') {
                            c.$setValidity('allowTab', false);
                        }
                        else {
                            c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
        }
    });
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/184/

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to keep the focus in the textbox after a tab character?

You have to use the preventDefault() method:

```
// ...
                // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
                this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);

                // put caret at right position again
                this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

                c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);

                e.preventDefault();

                // prevent the focus lose
                return false;

// ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/186/

Answer (score 1):

You update the textbox value and set the validation in jQuery - not in the angular lifecycle. To update the frontend in time you need to call scope.$digest() to sync the angular model with the dom.

```
                // put caret at right position again
                this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

                c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);
                scope.$digest();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/187/

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the Michael version and got it working exactly what I was looking for, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/190/

```
else if (e.keyCode !== 9 && e.type === 'keyup') {
    var hasTab = val.indexOf('\t') > -1;
    if(hasTab){
        c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);
    }
    else if(val == '') {
        c.$setValidity('allowTab', false);
    }
    else {
        c.$setValidity('allowTab', true);
    }                                     
    scope.$digest();
}
```